# Workflow is getting suspended for some users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, error

I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises. I am using SharePoint Designer workflow when new item will be created.
Here my this list is having unique permission then entire site. I am facing an issue that for some specific users workflow is going in Suspended state. I tried to make a log entry at step 1, but it is also not working.
When I go to workflow it gives me this error :

> RequestorId: 685fdde8-4e2c-7bd3-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400 {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"Title eq 'F \" is not valid."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["9"],"SPRequestGuid":["685fdde8-4e2c-7bd3-a9b9-a54ecc97a47e"],"request-id":["685fdde8-4e2c-7bd3-a9b9-a54ecc97a47e"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4667"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Wed, 24 Aug 2016 06:08:36 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

These users are having same permission as other users on entire site, my list and workflow history list.

Plsese guide me where I should check for this issue.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: I am agree with @Alex Burdin, please verify for that error.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to below error message:

```
The expression \"Title eq 'F \" is not valid
```

Especially the part, where there is no closing single quote.